# using linux grep with look ahead regexp

Tags: regex, grep

I have string in txt file

```
cat list.txt
userone@ex.com, usertwo@ex.com, userthree@ex.com
```

and i want to print every user login w/o **@ex.com** each new line and try to use regexp with linux grep

```
grep -oe '[a-z](?=@ex.com,)' list.txt
```

but nothing happens, why? It will be like:

```
userone
usertwo
userthree
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the `-P` option to use PCRE with `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `grep -P`, you can use `grep + cut`:

```sh
grep -oE '[^@ ]+@ex\.com' list.txt | cut -d@ -f1

userone
usertwo
userthree
```

With `gnu grep`:

```sh
grep -oP '[^@ ]+(?=@ex\.com)' list.txt

userone
usertwo
userthree
```